# Flask redirect not work after form submit over jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

Please, help me with problem: Flask don't want redirect after form submit.
Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
....
@app.route('/auth/')
def auth():
return render_template('auth.html')
```

This code work well:), auth.html render form:

```
{% extends "system.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form id="authen">
<input type="text" id="avtor_sku" pattern="[0-9]{1,13}" maxlength="13" value='' autofocus required>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Submit this form - over js-code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){$('#authen').submit( function(){ var avtor_sku = $("#avtor_sku").val();
data1= '' + avtor_sku;
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "/auth_echo/", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:  {auth_echo_value: data1}, success: function() {alert(1)}});  
return false;});});
```

Alert(1) in this code - work.
Route /auth_echo/:

```
@app.route('/auth_echo/', methods=['GET'])
def auth_echo():
return redirect(url_for('openday'))
```

Redirect not work. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot redirect after AJAX.

You can do something like this if you want to redirect:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://example.com",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href = data;
            }
        });
```

Note that is assumes data is a new url, but you can do `window.location.href=new_url` to "redirect"